# Getting the checkbox quantity in the list and setting it in textview

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an adapter that, as shown in the picture, has an item and two numbers and a checkbox. When I check the box, the number of Checkbox is set in  Textview and if I check the second check box, I want to sum it with the first value. And add to Textview

https://file.io/w1vppp

But I do not know how to do it

help me

thanks

Comment: https://file.io/5S8YVZ in pic

Comment: before setting the value into textview hold the value in variable and once you click on other checkbox add the check box value to the variable and then store in the same variable..like this you can achieve this